# What is the difference between "build" and "build with dependencies" in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans

Can anyone tell me what the difference is between 'build' and 'build with dependencies' commands in the NetBeans IDE?

Comment: Are you using Maven? See "Binding Maven goals to IDE actions" [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices) and see what they are mapped to.

Comment: Yes I'm using Maven. Both the "Build" and "Build with Dependencies" actions have the same execution goal of "install" in the project properties window. The only difference between the two actions is that you can tick a box on the "Build" action to also "Build with Dependencies". It does not explain the differences between the two though or what the "Build with Dependencies" tick box option adds to the regular "Build" action.

Comment: If they have the same execution goal, it seems to me that they do the same thing, unless you configure it otherwise. Is there any reason to suspect otherwise? E.g. does building with dependencies take significantly longer than just "build"?

Comment: The timing is very similar for both actions - it isn't exactly the same every time but I would say it has a negligible variance. I am only using a small project though so I would not expect any major timing differences anyway. I was just wondering if there was something I was missing or didn't know regarding the two actions. I compared the output messages but there are no differences there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html :

> The action mapped to "Build with Dependencies" builds the project using the Reactor plugin. When you build a project using the Reactor plugin, the dependencies of the sub-projects are built before the containing project is built.

So it seems that the usual "Build" action doesn't take into account the build order.

Comment: So should you clean and build and then "build with dependencies"? or do we need to clean?

Comment: I think that it's on a per case scenario. You should clean and then "build with dependencies" if some of your dependencies have changed and need rebuilding.